# Squashed display for top tag reputation gain

Tags: bug, profile-page, top-tag

I have noticed that the green reputation gain box on your "Top tag" indicator is the wrong size. It is too small/squashed:

[image]

Should we fix this to make it the same height as the tag itself? I think it would improve the UI of the user interface.